# What do "Secondary power supply/switch-over time" and the corresponding values in the table mean?

Tags: general-aviation, airport, aeronautical-information

What do "Secondary power supply/switch-over time" and the corresponding values in the table mean? I have no idea about the statements I marked in yellow in the table. I would be glad if you explain in detail. The table is from the Turkey AIP document.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Secondary power supply refers to alternate electricity source for runway lights in case the main power supply is interrupted at facility or larger scale.

Switch over time refers to time it takes to switch over to the backup power source. Zero seconds means there is no interruption in lighting.

Zero switch over time requires a battery system (UPS) to deliver power while generator is starting. Batteries alone will not be able to keep the lights on for very long, basically the alternate power source is always a generator.

Comment: A very logical, simple and descriptive answer. I am grateful.

Comment: @pilot162 as a sidenote, I can tell you it's quite a spectacle when such a UPS battery system suddenly decides to identify as smoke and fire instead of a solid 

Comment: I hope the system doesn't want to identify itself this way all of a sudden :D

Comment: That has actually happened 

Comment: Of course, we don't know where and when, I hope it was solved in a short time without any problems :)